# How to read from property file in web.xml

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, web.xml

in my **web.xml** i want to read the welcome file from property file 
something like:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>${home.page}</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

i have **propertyPlaceholderConfigurer** configured:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>

                <value>classpath:messages/application.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

is there's additional param should be added to web.xml, or another bean needs to be defined or what ?

also i have another xml file on the same level of web.xml (under WEB-INF direclty)
can i read from property file in it in the same way ?

please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work like that; the `web.xml` file is *completely* unrelated to Spring.

What you *could* do is have a hard-coded welcome file, and inside *that* file, redirect to something defined in the Spring configuration, retrieving the page by grabbing the Spring context manually.

Comment: so, there's no way of reading value from property file inside web.xml ?

Comment: @fresh_dev I don't know if there's *absolutely* no way, but it's the *container* that loads `web.xml`, and the container doesn't know anything about Spring at all by default. You're better off approaching it in a different way, IMO.

Comment: i am not talking about spring only, i am talking in general if there's a way that's why i tagged javaee.

Comment: btw, any ideas how to read from property file in another .xml file under web-inf (url-rewrite file)

Comment: @fresh_dev If you're using a build system you could rewrite web.xml staticly using a variety of mechanisms. For load-time replacement, I *think* you might be able to specify a `-D` startup property, but that obviously wouldn't come from a config file, and I'm not sure if it's cross-container or not.

Comment: Check the [Java Servlet Specification 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=315), there is no `web.xml` property substitution in it. I agree with @Dave's answers, the mentioned ways are the best you can do.